# When can a $k$-cycle wrap around a manifold?

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, topology, branes

According to the paper ``[Heterotic and Type I String Dynamics from Eleven Dimensions](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9510209)'' (page 7):

> Even when the topology is wrong -- for instance on $\mathbb{R}^{11}$ where there is no two-cycle for the membrane to wrap around -- macroscopic membrane solutions (with a scale much bigger than the Planck scale) will make sense, but we do not assume they can be quantized to recover gravitons.

This seems like a result from basic topology that I ought to know. But in general, how do I know whether there is a $k$-cycle for a membrane to wrap around a given manifold $\mathcal{M}$?

**In this particular case**, is it just that $\mathbb{R}^{11}$ has genus 0, and hence not even a one cycle to wrap around?

Possibly related thread which does not answer my question: [What does it mean to "wrap" a D-brane around some manifold?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103520/what-does-it-mean-to-wrap-a-d-brane-around-some-manifold)